# get body content @Context HttpServletRequest java jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am using Jersey and I am trying to access the request body in my method very similar to this question:

**How do I read request body for a RESTful service using Jersey?**

Body value send i with Postman.

```
   @Path("/updateanfrage")
       public class UpdateAnfrage extends ResourceConfig
        {
          private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UpdateAnfrage.class);

        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        public UpdateInformation beschaffeUpdateInformation(ClientInformation clientinformation,
                @Context HttpHeaders headers, @Context UriInfo uriDetails,  @Context Request request, @Context HttpServletRequest requestContext) throws SecurityException, IOException
        {
             UpdateInformation updateinformation = new UpdateInformation();
             log.info("Method -- " + request.getMethod());
             log.info("Complete URI -- "+ uriDetails.getRequestUri().toString());
             log.info("Content Type -- "+ requestContext.getContentType());
            // log.info("Body -- "+ requestContext.getReader().lines());
             ...
             ...
            return updateinformation;
        }
```

Comment: Create a ClientInformation POJO and annotate it using JAXB. Then you can directly access clientInformation inside your  beschaffeUpdateInformation method. This method should also return an instance of UpdateInformation.

Comment: I want to read XML(String) und write it to a file log.txt

Comment: What does ClientInformation look like?

Comment: import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

  @XmlRootElement(name = "ClientInformation")
  @XmlType(propOrder = { "firma", "version", "personalisierung" })
  public class ClientInformation
  {
 public Firma firma;
 public Version version;
 public Personalisierung personalisierung;

 // default constructor
 public ClientInformation()
 {
  firma = new Firma();
  version = new Version();
  personalisierung = new Personalisierung();
 }
  }

Comment: Update your question with this information, it's hard to read this as a comment. You may also add the definitions for Firma and Version respectively.

Comment: I need no information from the client information object, I would have that as xml string from body request

Comment: Why don't you just log your xml as log.info(clientInformation.firma.getName()); I assumed that Firma has a field name. Of course, log as many fields you need to.

Comment: Because I need raw XML that comes from request. This is my task.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to create a filter (that implements `ContainerRequestFilter`) and process the input stream.

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext req){

  //init logger
  final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UpdateAnfrage.class);

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getEntityStream(),"UTF-8"));

  StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            xml.append(line);
        }

   req.setEntityStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
   logger.info(xml);

  }

}
```